# How to set offset to clock in Kernel Module

Tags: linux, kernel-module

How do I tune the clock in my kernel module ? 
I want to set an offset to the clock from my kernel module. The functionality can be similar to `adjtimex` (in `user-space`). How do I do the same in kernel space?